# Is there a way to prevent the 404 error for consumer accounts when attempting to fetch non-consumer data?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I have an application that fetches profile data using Microsoft Graph APIs. The application should be able to fetch profiles for both Work/School Azure account and consumer Azure accounts. The issue I have is that when I am retrieving data that is exposed on Work/School accounts but not a consumer accounts, I get a 404 error. In other words, my application should handle Work/School accounts and consumer accounts the same, only fetching data that is exposed by Microsoft Graph for a consumer account without returning an error when data is unexposed.

Calling this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` with authorization token for a consumer account, I get the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(etc)/$entity",
    "displayName": "<fullname>",
    "surname": "<lastname>",
    "givenName": "<firstname>",
    "id": "value",
    "userPrincipalName": "value@hotmail.com",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null
}
```

Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=birthday` with a Work/School account, I get data I can work with. Meanwhile calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=birthday` with the same authorization token returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5dac0b98-0335-4de2-b8fa-3b9a2dfbe378",
            "date": "2019-04-26T23:23:21"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve the profile data for a consumer account while still attempting to retrieve the unexposed data in a Work/School account without getting a 404 returned?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requesting data that doesn't exist (`birthday`), you *should* be getting a `404 Not Found` response. Per [RFC 7231 Section 6.5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) :

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: When I call GET on this endpoint, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=birthda`, it returns the standard profile success response, so 404s are only returned on fields that are restricted from being accessed with a consumer access token.

Comment: Those fields are not "restricted", they simply do not exist. This is why you get a `404 (Not Found)` and not a `403 (Forbidden)`. Consumer accounts _are not stored in AAD_, they use their own backend system.

Comment: Graph knows what properties belong to an entity which is why it knows to just ignore `birthda` but not `birthday`. In other words, when it makes the request to the backend API, it knows to not ask for `birthda` but since `birthday` does exist on the `User` resource it sends to the underlying Outlook.com API and receives a `404` response.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies it for me. Thanks.